# Get type definitions from imported files not marked with @flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

**TL;DR** How do I tell `flow` to import type definitions from imported modules not declared with `@flow`?

### Longer version

Flow seams to be able to derive types from files not using the flow syntax (see example).

#### Example file 'flow.js'

```
if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
  var y = "hello";
} else {
  var y = 2;
}

var i = y;
```

#### Command 'flow suggest flow.js'

```
if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
-  var y = "hello";
+  var y: number | string = "hello";
 } else {
-  var y = 2;
+  var y: number | string = 2;
 }
-var i = y;
+var i: number | string = y;
```

It also seam to be able to list all imports from a specific file using `flow get-importers`. The tools seams to be there but I can't figure out how to automatically tell `flow` to get the type definitions from my imports not declared with `@flow`.

I would like it to traverse down the import chain, calculate the types and use them in files marked with `@flow`. I do not want it type check code not marked with `@flow`, only retrieve the types.

Comment: I do not  understand exactly, maybe can this code;
var a = 1;
console.log(a.constructor.name); 
var b = eval(a.constructor.name)(a);

Comment: I'm not following.

Comment: According to [the documentation regarding modules](https://flowtype.org/docs/modules.html#missingrequired-annotations): "Flow is able to infer most types in your program for you, but there is one restriction imposed on this rule: You must annotate the exports of a module explicitly.".

Comment: @HiDeo ... and that's what I'm trying to solve :)

Answer (score 2):

I reword your question to what I believe you mean.

> How do I create type definitions for files that Flow does not know about?

There's two things:

- If the file is owned by you (i.e. not a third party lib inside `node_modules` or such), then you can create a `*.js.flow` file next to it that documents its exports.
- If the file is *not* owned by you (i.e. third party lib inside `node_modules` or such), then you can create a libdef file inside `flow-typed/name-of-library.js`

For `.js.flow` files you write the definitions like this:

```
// @flow
declare module.exports: { ... }
```

For libdef files you write the definitions like this:

```
declare module "my-third-party-library" {
  declare module.exports: { ... }
}
```

Hopefully that answers your question

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't. I'm looking for an automated way to derive type annotations on all imports, recursively, in my project.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking for, you'll need to rephrase it better

Comment: Anything in particular you want me to clarify? Note the tools I referred to `flow suggestion`, `flow get-importers`.

Comment: Are you looking for a script that runs `flow suggest` for every module in `get-importers`? Or are you asking to update the modules with the results of `flow suggest`

Comment: I want flow to type check all files annotated with `@flow` and derive the types from the entire import chain. So if module `A` imports `B` and only `A` has the `@flow` tag, it should still be able to use the types from `B` – but it should not type check `B`. So only files taged with `@flow` shows up when using `flow check`.

Comment: Could you remove your answer? It doesn't answer the question.