# Flow-typed - Generate Libdef

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

I'm using Flow to help author a JS project.  If I want to provide a [libdef file](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/)  to supplement it do I need to create it manually, or am I able to execute some magic command that I'm not aware of yet which will generate the lib def for me?

Something like `$ flow-typed doyourmagic` would be nice.

EDIT:

Found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38906578/192999

Which says:

> There's two things:
>
> If the file is owned by you (i.e. not a third party lib inside node_modules or such), then you can create a *.js.flow file next to it that documents its exports.
>
> If the file is not owned by you (i.e. third party lib inside node_modules or such), then you can create a libdef file inside flow-typed/name-of-library.js
>
> For .js.flow files
>   you write the definitions like this:

```
// @flow 
declare module.exports: { ... }
```

> For libdef files you write the definitions like this:

```
declare module "my-third-party-library" {   declare module.exports: {... } }
```

For my question I fall into the "is owned by you" camp.

I guess I'm confused as to:

1. How I write these files.
2. How/where I publish these files to package it up for another project to reference.

Also, why do I need to create the .js.flow file manually?  Can this not be magically generated?  Perhaps that's the intention going forward but not implemented yet.

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice [guide](https://medium.com/@ryyppy/shipping-flowtype-definitions-in-npm-packages-c987917efb65) showing how to package flow code together with the compiled code. So:

1. You do not have to write your own libdefs, you can use the entire flow source code. If you want a definition with only the type declarations, you can look into `flow gen-flow-files`, although that is still experimental and might fail.
2. You can package them as `*.js.flow` and the flow checker will automatically pick those up when you import your library.

Comment: But what do you do, if you have a bundled package? I `rollup` the code to make require faster (1 mid size file vs. 300 littles files), but then copying the source files as *.js.flow won't work as there is no corresponding *.js file anymore, or will it?